# Absolute Cell References Breaking

Tags: excel

I have 3000 formulas that all have absolute cell references. I set them as the spreadsheets are accessed by about 50 people, and many people delete excess rows or insert rows even though we've instructed not to. I had thought that absolute cell references wouldn't break if a cell or a row was deleted, however it's still happening. They turn into #REF! and throw off all formulas further down in the chain.

I've manually fixed the absolute references a few times; however this takes a large amount of time that I won't have given a few weeks.

The formula is as follows, repeating in cells F1 through F3000:

```
=IF(AND($a$1>0,ISBLANK($d$1)),$a$1,"n/a")
```

They are then crosschecked for any that aren't n/a by a formula, as follows:

```
=IF(MIN(F1:F300)=0,"100%",MIN(F1:F3000))
```

The hope is that the formula that crosschecks for the lowest non-zero result, and will then spit out a date. Either changing the formulas with the absolute references so they won't result in #REF!, or changing the formula that cross references them so it ignores #REF! would work. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Didn't mention this at first, but the formulas are on a separate sheet. The data's entered on one of many different sheets, then referenced for data calculations on a different one. This is done to help keep the individual sheets as tidy as possible.

Comment: You've misunderstood what Absolute Addressing does.  They _will_ update when rows/columns are inserted above/to left.  They will convert to Ref Errors if the referenced cell is deleted.   What they do do, is when a cell containing absolute addresses is _copied_ the resulting address is unchanged (unlike Relative Addressing)

Comment: Please update your Q to properly describe your situation.   By trying to "simplify" things,  you've inadvertently hidden critical details required to solve your problem

Comment: try if this method work > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713539/how-to-prevent-absolute-references-from-changing-in-excel/67716949#67716949

Answer (score 1):

You can always ignore errors by wrapping the formula in an IFError function.

```
=Iferror(IF(MIN(F1:F300)=0,"100%",MIN(F1:F3000)),"")
```

I'm not quite clear why you use absolute references, if the formula is applied to cells F1 to F3000. It appears that the formula refers to cells in the current row. In this case, relative references would be a lot better, because they will survive the deletion of rows.

So, change `=IF(AND($a$1>0,ISBLANK($d$1)),$a$1,"n/a")` to `=IF(AND(A1>0,ISBLANK(d1)),a1,"n/a")`

Comment: The referenced cells are actually on different sheets. I'd simplified the formula slightly to keep it a little easier to read. There's a large number of other formulas, and columns with Pick Lists that are all kept on a separate sheet from where data is entered. I tried the Iferror wrapper, but if there's an error it just ignores the rest of the formula and won't spit out the date.

Comment: So, the IfError approach would work for you, then? Also, consider protecting the sheet that the formulas reference, so people cannot delete rows.

Comment: The Iferror was not working, at least not in a way that I could find. Protecting the sheets so that rows cannot be deleted will work though, it means fixing the sheet one last time then never having to worry about it again. Thank you so much for pointing out that option, I don't know how I missed it!

Comment: you may 'accept' (click on the tick) the answer if it is acceptable.. (as a tq sign) | Vote up is a plus.. ( :