# How to prevent absolute references from changing in excel?

Tags: excel

If I have an absolute reference pointing to a2 and insert a row in a1, the absolute reference $a$2 changes to $a$3.

Is there any way to prevent the absolute reference from changing?

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner: Interesting approach, although that only prevents the reference from changing vertically, not horizontally/across columns

Comment: @ThomasLilleng That is correct but using INDIRECT or OFFSET make the formula volatile, one or two of them will not effect the performance but use it too much and it will slow down Excel to the point that the user experience suffers.  There are also ways around that: `=INDEX(A:XFD,2,1)`  Now it will only calculate if a value on that sheet changes not if a value changes anywhere in any open excel workbooks like it would with a volatile function.  It is about knowing how the sheet is used and working with it.

Comment: @ScottCraner That I support, and your point here should be valuable information for the OP to consider if the workbook is heavily loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use INDIRECT like this:

```
=INDIRECT("A2")
```

Or like this if you need it to absolute to the sheet as well

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2")
```